# Angular 13 routing to Login page

Tags: angular, routes, angular13

```
<app-navbar></app-navbar>
<div class = "app-body">
<div class="app-sidebar">
    <app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
</div> 
<div class="app-feed">
    <router-outlet name="main"></router-outlet>       
</div> 
</div>
```

I want to show login page without the sidebar and navbar component. When user hits the url login page will show without navbar nad sidebar. After successful login homepage should be shown. How to achieve this?

Comment: This can be solved with nested router-outlets combined with childRoutes. Idea is to only have a router outlet in app.component and in there, using routing, router either layout1 or layout2 (so login and the rest). Your example html would then go in Layout 2 (full, with menus etc).

Answer (score 2):

> Change your html like this:

```
<app-navbar *ngIf="connected"></app-navbar>
    <div class = "app-body" *ngIf="connected">
    <div class="app-sidebar">
        <app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
    </div> 
    <div class="app-feed">
        <router-outlet name="main"></router-outlet>       
    </div> 
    </div>
```

> In your .ts add this

......

```
connected=false;

contructor(private authService:AuthService){

}

ngOnit(){
  

    this.authService.user.subscribe(
         {
          next:()=>{this.connected=true}
          }
    )

}
```

> You have to create your AuthService for login end add field user type of  Subject or
> BehaviourSubject
> In your login method after user connect add user.next(value)

For exemple AuthService :

```
export class AuthService {

  public user: BehaviorSubject<User> = new BehaviorSubject<User>({});

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient, private router: Router, private commonService: CommonService) {
  }

  login(email: string, password: string): Observable<User> {
    return this.httpClient.post<TokenAccess>('api/auth/connexion', {username: email, password: password});
  }

  logout() {
    this.user.next({});
    this.router.navigate(['/login']).then()
  }


}
```

And login component

```
    .....
    constructor(private authService:AuthService){}
    
    login(email, password){
     this.authService.login(email.password).subscribe({
      next:(value)=>{this.authService.user.next(value)};
      error:(err)=>{console.log(err);}
    })

    }
.....
```